# list object no attribute capitalize() , title() and upper()

Tags: python, list, syntax-error, list-comprehension

I'm doing some python programming and i'm working on list comprehension when this error appeared. I want to convert the list below so that they all start with an uppercase letter like this:  L_upper =["Hello","And","Goodbye"]

```
L = ["hello","and","goodbye"]
L_upper = [ L.capitalize() for i in L]
print (L_upper)
```

This only give me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'capitalize' error
I have also tried using L.upper() and L.title(),but same error. What am I missing? do I need to import something?

Comment: Just read what the error message is trying to tell you. The _list_ object has no attribute _capitalize_. You applied the method `capitalize()` on an object of type `list`. Looking at the flawed code for more than a minute should be enough to deduce the source of this issue. Also better variable naming would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change:

```
L_upper = [ L.capitalize() for i in L]
```

in:

```
L_upper = [ i.capitalize() for i in L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because in the list comprehension you need to capitalize each element in the list. So you have to do something such as i.upper() and not L.upper().The list (L in this case) has no attribute .upper(). The only thing with that attribute are the individual elements in the list (i in this case). Here is the proper code that will get you the output that you are looking for.

```
L = ["hello", "and", "goodbye"]

L_upper = [i.upper() for i in L]
print(L_upper)

['HELLO', 'AND', 'GOODBYE']
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: thanks this way is simple and easy.